# Python Function Decoration In This Instance

Tags: python

```
def images_custom_list(args, producer_data):
    tenant, token, url = producer_data
    url = url.replace(".images", ".servers")

    url = url + '/' + 'detail'
    output = do_request(url, token)
    output = output[0].json()["images"]
    custom_images_list = [custom_images for custom_images in output 
            if custom_images["metadata"].get('user_id', None)]
    temp_image_list = []
    for image in custom_images_list:
        image_temp  = ( { "status": image["status"], 
            "links": image["links"][0]["href"], 
            "id": image["id"], "name": image["name"]} )
        temp_image_list.append(image_temp)
    print json.dumps(temp_image_list, indent=2)

def image_list_detail(args, producer_data):
    tenant, token, url = producer_data
    url = url.replace(".images", ".servers")

    uuid = args['uuid']
    url = url + "/" + uuid
    output = do_request(url, token)
    print output[0]
```

I am trying to make the code more efficient and clean looking by utilizing the Python's function decoration. Since these 2 functions share the same first 2 lines, how could I make a function decorator with these 2 lines and have these 2 functions be decorated it?

Comment: While you could do this with decorators, this looks like stateful information with associated methods, which means maybe you should be thinking about using an object for this instead.

Comment: I would use objects, but there is no data that I need to retain.

Comment: Objects don't *necessarily* have to be long lived to be appropriate or useful.  If you are worried about performance, using a decorator imposes overhead as instantiation would, but with what I would argue is a less clear piece of code.  Instead of a decorator, consider putting the shared code in an `__init__` method, then make the unique blocks methods of the object.  If the object is really throwaway for you, you could just do `result = MyClass(producer_data).image_list_detail(args)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a way to solve it:

```
from functools import wraps

def fix_url(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwarg):
        kwarg['url'] = kwarg['url'].replace(".images", ".servers")
        return function(*args, **kwarg)
    return wrapper

@fix_url
def images_custom_list(args, tenant=None, token=None, url=None):
    url = url + '/' + 'detail'
    output = do_request(url, token)
    output = output[0].json()["images"]
    custom_images_list = [custom_images for custom_images in output 
            if custom_images["metadata"].get('user_id', None)]
    temp_image_list = []
    for image in custom_images_list:
        image_temp  = ( { "status": image["status"], 
            "links": image["links"][0]["href"], 
            "id": image["id"], "name": image["name"]} )
        temp_image_list.append(image_temp)
    print json.dumps(temp_image_list, indent=2)

@fix_url
def image_list_detail(args, tenant=None, token=None, url=None):
    uuid = args['uuid']
    url = url + "/" + uuid
    output = do_request(url, token)
    print output[0]
```

sadly for you, you may notice that you need to get rid of `producer_data`, but have it split in multiple arguments because you cannot factorize that part of the code, as you'll anyway need to split it again in each of the functions. I chose to use keyword arguments (by setting a default value to `None`), but you could use positional arguments as well, your call.

BTW, note that it's not making the code more efficient, though it's helping in making it a bit more readable (you know that you're changing the URL the same way for both methods, and when you fix the URL changing part, it's done the same way everywhere), but it's making 2 more function calls each time you call the function, so it's in no way more "efficient".

N.B.: It's basically based over @joel-cornett's example (I wouldn't have used `@wraps` otherwise, just plain old double function decorator), I just specialized it. (I don't think he deserves a -1)
Please at least `+1` his answer or accept it.

But I think a simpler way to do it would be:

```
def fix_url(producer_data):
    return (producer_data[0], producer_data[1], producer_data[2].replace(".images", ".servers"))

def images_custom_list(args, producer_data):
    tenant, token, url = fix_url(producer_data)

    # stuff ...

def image_list_detail(args, producer_data):
    tenant, token, url = fix_url(producer_data)

    # stuff ...
```

which uses a simpler syntax (no decorator) and does only one more function call.

Comment: Not only is it adding extra function calls, it's also adding the overhead of creating a closure object under the covers, along with the extra attribute lookup overhead of retrieving values from closure scope.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def my_timesaving_decorator(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        execute_code_common_to_multiple_function()

        #Now, call the "unique" code
        #Make sure that if you modified the function args,
        #you pass the modified args here, not the original ones.
        return function(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Comment: -1 This is so generic as to be pretty much completely unhelpful in actually helping the OP solve his problem.  At least make some reference to what he's specified in his actual problem...